# Headless chrome with Selenium and Java in a Docker container

Tags: java, selenium, docker

I am trying to run a headless Chrome browser in a Docker container using a Docker file but is giving crash issue whenever it tries to execute the Automation script using it.

I have tried changing the Chrome driver version to 75 and 76 and gave issue with the Chrome browser version.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: I am currently trying it with Chrome driver version 78.0.3904.11 and it gave me the above error

Unable to load browser: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Did you try --disable-gpu?

Comment: Yes I did and after some research over the internet it turned out that it holds true only in the case of Windows machines, whereas for Docker I am using Linux machine.

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)?

Comment: Do those steps mentioned work for Linux OS as well in a Docker image?

Comment: Don't know, please try it yourself.

Comment: It did not work in my case, still seeing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

https://hub.docker.com/r/markhobson/maven-chrome/

I used this image from Docker Hub and it is now working for me.

Thank you, all for your valuable inputs, they were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome browser 74 and use chromedriver version as 74.0.3729.6.
Seems like some issue with latest chrome driver version

Comment: Okay, but do I add a specific version on Chrome browser as Chrome does not allow doing that. It updates automatically

Comment: Try to install unstable chrome 74 version. 
Use below command for installation



`apt-get update
apt-get install wget
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-unstable/google-chrome-unstable_74.0.3729.6-1_amd64.deb
apt-get install -f ./google-chrome-unstable_74.0.3729.6-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: It is failing with this error

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -f ./google-chrome-unstable_74.0.3729.6-1_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: @Anand, use `dpkg -i google-chrome-unstable_74.0.3729.6-1_amd64.deb` to install